# detect if an image is generally red, green, blue, or black

Tags: image, graphics, image-processing, colors

I'm processing small images that will either be red, green, blue, or black (think card ranks in a 4-color deck). What's a good, fast algorithm to determine which color the image is?

For an example set of inputs, see [here](http://images.quickblogcast.com/95445-88129/ClassicDeck_MagnumOmahaCards.jpg?a=68), except the images can be scaled and such so they won't be as clear-cut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works sufficiently well for one pixel:

```
def get_ishness(r,g,b):
    h,s,v = rgb_to_hsv(r,g,b) #h from 0-360, s and v from 0-100
    if v < 50: return 'black'
    if s < 15: return None
    if h < 10: return 'red'
    if 80 < h < 100: return 'green'
    if 210 < h < 230: return 'blue'
    return None
```

For the whole image, I sum up the pixels that are red,green,blue, and black, and return the color of which there are the most pixels.

Answer (score 2):

Are these the *exact* images you are using? If so, is there a single pixel on all images that will be coloured? I was thinking where the suit is. Look at a pixel where the suit should be and that will tell you what "colour" the card is.

More general approaches might include analysing the whole image (slow but effective), scaling the image down and analysing every pixel (more feasible if you end up with a small image but scaling may affect colours), or sampling at random *n* pixels (or rows/columns of pixels), maybe something with masking if the *shades* of colours are known ahead of time, but do you need a general approach?

Oh - another idea: Do you control the source of the input images? Maybe you could override some image metadata tage with a number to indicate the "colour". It's sort of cheating since there's no real image processing involved, and it's vulnerable to the tags getting stripped/modified, but it's probably the fastest method.

Comment: i do need a general approach - i won't be using those images in particular, and i won't know in advance what they are. given one pixel, then, how do i tell whether that pixel is red, green, blue, or black, considering that a red pixel might be (255,0,0) or (255,31,12) or (253,127,114), etc?

Comment: @Claudiu: Ah, so you have also "reddish" pixels? You'd have to define a range of "red", I imagine. Consider, what would you do if someone input an orange or pink?

Comment: @Claudiu: You may want to look into colour histograms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_histogram

Comment: i would count pink as light-red, but not orange. i guess i'll just have to analyze the images im using and see what generall passes as 'red' for them

Comment: ah thanks for the histogram link. it seems i should convert to HSV color space and look for ranges there

Answer (score 1):

This post seems to have settled but if you don't mind my 2 cents...

As I take it, you need a general approach and you don't know what the images are in advance. While the answers already posted should be good enough for quick coding with maybe some adjustments, if you still run into problems with them I suggest you use a self-organizing map: http://davis.wpi.edu/~matt/courses/soms/ and http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/som/som1.html

It might need some (unsupervised) training time to get a decent map/recognizer (hey, it's a neural network after all), but I've encountered a problem a bit like yours and they worked well for me (easy to adapt, flexible with different lighting, etc.).